# Django1.10 Error: django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-dynamic-scraper

I am using Django 1.10, and trying to use the **django-dynamic-scraper** package following the tutorial: http://django-dynamic-scraper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

I have encountered the problem when I was calling "python manage.py makemigrations" :**RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.**

The full version is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 305, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 385, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 372, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 310, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 303, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/zhangjintao/WorkingPlace/dds/dds/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 267, in urls
    return self.get_urls(), 'admin', self.name
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 225, in get_urls
    from django.contrib.contenttypes import views as contenttype_views
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 138, in <module>
    class ContentType(models.Model):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 113, in __new__
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

But my installed apps contain the **django.contrib.contenttypes** :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app',
    'dynamic_scraper.models',
]
```

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from dynamic_scraper.models import Scraper, SchedulerRuntime
from scrapy_djangoitem import DjangoItem


class NewsWebsite(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.URLField()
    scraper = models.ForeignKey(Scraper, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    scraper_runtime = models.ForeignKey(SchedulerRuntime, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    news_website = models.ForeignKey(NewsWebsite)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    url = models.URLField()
    checker_runtime = models.ForeignKey(SchedulerRuntime, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class ArticleItem(DjangoItem):
    django_model = Article
```

My admin.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Article, NewsWebsite, ArticleItem
# Register your models here.


@admin.register(Article, ArticleItem, NewsWebsite)
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


class NewWebsiteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


class ArticleItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

The urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

The folder structure looks like this:

[image: Folder Structure Image]

I'm confused what's wrong with my code...

Comment: what's an output of `manage.py showmigrations`?

Comment: Can you add `/dds/dds/urls.py` file ?

Comment: @valignatev  I tried, still the same error.

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge Uploaded it. (I haven't done anything to it, so it's complete in default..)

Answer (score 0):

`dynamic_scraper` section in `INSTALLED_APPS` should go without `.models`. e.g.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'dynamic_scraper',
]
```

Also, since you're using `1.10`, it worth to add an `AppConfig` for your application: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig)

Comment: Just tried to install dynamic-scraper myself with django 1.10 and it worked for me. What exact versions are you using? Maybe worth to post `pip freeze` output in your question. Also, fix `dynamic_scraper.models` to `dynamic_scraper` if you tried it, so people won't respond with the same answer